# How to make a scheduler by using PHP like scheduler email on the server?

Tags: php, timer, scheduler

```
$sec = $_POST['sec'];
$min = $_POST['min'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$diff = strtotime('2018-05-28 22:31:20')-time(); //convert datetime to second
$future  = time() + $diff; //count down

sleep($diff);
```

Should I convert the `$sec`, `$min`, `$hours`... etc on `('2018-05-28 22:31:20')` into
`($sec, $min, $hours, $day, $month, $year)`?

What is the best way to improve the code and make the scheduler and delay for 10 hours or 25 hours?

Comment: Have you tried with a corn job??

Comment: I know cron job, but I need it to run with the serve such as Cpanel serve

Comment: You can add cronjob in Cpanel itself. Add the file path and your delay and it will run again and again after that specific time interval

Comment: Is that still possible to do it without cron job? I barely use cron.

Comment: I don't think so, PHP is an on demand language, so if you don't have a request you cant take an action

Comment: PHP doesn't have anything like background tasks. You need some way to trigger the script at a certain time. That's exactly what a con job does,  so why would you want to use something else?

Comment: I saw that CodeIgniter Web Framework may schedule task. I saw a lot of cron job PHP but I am failed on make that.

Comment: CI doesn't run the scripts in the background by itself. As already mentioned, you need something to trigger the PHP scripts and that's the sole purpose of Cron. If you have tried cron and can't get that to work, then show us what you've tried and we might be able to help you with that. But if you want some script to run at specific times/intervals, you need to use cron.

Comment: I need some source of how to setup cron job on serve.

Comment: Anyone know how to setup cron job in PHP?

Comment: @JavaScript you don't set up cron jobs using PHP, they are configured on the server. You can google examples very easily, and also instructions for your specific operating system or hosting control panel

Answer (score -1):

```
$sec = $_POST['sec'];
$min = $_POST['min'];
$hours = $_POST['hours'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$month = $_POST['month'];
$year = $_POST['year'];

$diff = strtotime('2018-05-28 22:31:20')-time(); //convert datetime to second
$future  = time() + $diff; //count down

ignore_user_abort();//shut down the web connect
set_time_limit(0);// change php rnu time limite


sleep($diff);
```